# Animation VO rig build from scratch

Tags: recording, gear, voice-over, animation, booth

I'm Tom I'm based in the UK, this is my first time posting here, so please go easy on me if I come across like I'm asking a dumb question, because if you don't ask etc.

A local college (not a university) has asked me to help them build a VO booth and control room. My background was in broadcast radio, so acoustics and wiring aren't a problem.

However I'd be interested to know what you would pick gear wise based on your past experience and workflow if you were building your own set up from scratch? The budget is £30k.

So far I've chosen 4 Neumann TLM 193's and the media studies depth insisted on Reaper. But I'm stuck for ideas on mic pre's/outboard compressors/desk etc. So I'd be interested to hear your take.

Tom.

Comment: I think we'd need to know a lot more. For example, how many voice actors in the booth at a time? One thing I find a bit odd up front is with that budget they could afford software that is more widely used than Reaper. I love Reaper, but it is lacking in some areas and if I were trying to impart useful skills onto students, I would be more inclined to make them learn software that is popular the in the professional world, less easy to learn, and harder to afford, like Pro Tools. They can easily learn to use Reaper on their own.

Comment: I argued that Pro Tools would be the better option, because it's the most ubiquitous DAW in the industry. Sadly the head of dept is mad for Reaper and feels he knows what's best for the job. The booth will be for four people per session, at a squeeze maybe six people at a time.